# Possibility to install ML directly from the hard disk?

Tags: macos, install

Does it possible to install Mountain Lion (clean install) without using USB key or DVD?

I'm currently running on SL, and I want install ML (I already have the dmg file).

Answer (score 1):

If you boot into the **Recovery HD** (<kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>⌥ alt/option</kbd> then select Recovery), you can open **Disk Utility** and **Erase** the internal drive.

Then close Disk Utility and use the **Reinstall** option in OS X Utilities to reinstall OS X.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. By the way, I'm currently running on SL, and I want install ML (I already have the dmg file).

Comment: It's ok, this post helped me a lot: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80052/is-it-possible-to-put-mountain-lions-install-on-an-hdd-partition?rq=1